# Erro ao criar projeto Laravel

Tags: laravel

```
C:\xampp\htdocs>laravel new blog
Crafting application...
```

> [Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\RuntimeException]
>     TTY mode is not supported on Windows platform.
>
> new [--dev] [--] name

sabe me dizer que erro é esse?

Comment: Especifique melhor os passos para reproduzir seu problema Cleber. O que você vez até chegar nesse problema?

Comment: Qual a versão que esta utilizando do Laravel ? Detalhe mais.

Comment: Estou usando a versão 1.3.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simples, para resolver vá até seu composer.json na pasta `C:\users\myname\appdata\Roaming\Composer\composer.json` (mais ou menos isso).`

Modifique:

`"laravel/installer": "^1.3"` para `"laravel/installer": "^1.3 !=1.3.2"`.

Em seguida rode o comando: `composer global update`.

Comment: Ok resolvido!!! Valeu galera!!!