# Diferença entre comandos laravel new project e composer create-project

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer

Qual a diferença entre os comandos `laravel new nome-projeto` e `composer create-project laravel/laravel nome-projeto --prefer-dist`?

Em ambos os casos o resultado é o mesmo mas no caso do via composer, a pasta com do projeto ocupa muito mais espaço.

Qual a melhor forma de trabalhar para a versão 5.1 do framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A diferença entre eles é bem sutil. Ambos vão utilizar o composer para instalar as dependências do seu projeto.

A diferença é que o `--prefer-dist` do composer irá baixar a partir dos [releases do projeto](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/releases) e o `laravel new` de um [domínio prórpio](https://github.com/laravel/installer/blob/master/src/NewCommand.php#L109) (http://cabinet.laravel.com/latest.zip).

Acho o `composer create-project` mais flexível pois é possível instalar uma versão específica, no Laravel Installer isso não é possível.

Sobre o tamanho do projeto, ambos ficam exatamente iguais:

[image: Dirs]

Comment: Sobre o tamanho da pasta, estou confirmando aqui o tamanho. Talvez seja uma medição errada, ou o composer create-project não baixou direto do dist

Comment: boa gmsantos , muito bem explicado, eu achava que o laravel new seria melhor ja que através dele o projeto fica bem menor nos meus testes. Aqui o projeto deu em torno de 20Mb com o composer create

Comment: acho que meu problema com o laravel new esta sendo causado por estar rodando ele no windows. Assim que rodo o comando tenho recebido o seguinte retorno  

[Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\RuntimeException]  TTY mode is not supported on Windows platform.

Embora o projeto tenha criado todos os diretórios vou pesquisar mais sobre o erro e posto aqui caso encontre a solução

Comment: No caso do erro " [Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\RuntimeException] TTY mode is not supported on Windows platform" o erro estava relacionado a versão do composer. Seguindo os passos da questão http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/120127/erro-ao-criar-projeto-laravel eu realizei o update do composer e ao gerar os projetos via laravel new e composer new o tamanho do projeto ficou idêntico. Seguindo as informações do gmsantos, irei adotar o composer create para os novos projetos. Obrigado pela ajuda